# Resolver problema matemático en Java

Tags: java, matemáticas

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto el cual tengo el siguiente problema.

Suponiendo que tengo dos artículos con las siguientes propiedades:

**NOMBRE**, **VALOR** Y **CANTIDAD**, el valor puede ser cualquiera, de ejemplo pondré que:

- `articulo1 = 1,300` pesos
- `articulo2 = 2300` pesos

necesito obtener cuales cantidades pueden tener estos dos artículos para que me de un total en rango de:

- **39,000** a **42,000** pesos.

Alguna idea? no utilice programación para darme a entender un poco mejor, estoy utilizando Java.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Podriamos ayudarte mejor viendo un poco de código y saber de manera puntual el estado actual de tu trabajo.

Comment: Podrías explicar de mejor manera con un ejemplo puntual, lo que te entiendo es que 30 articulos1 te darían un total de 39000, osea que 30 es una posibilidad ya que están en el rango que mencionas, o combinación de los dos artículos para que estén en ese rango??

Comment: Se me ocurren al menos dos formas de resolverlo, pero escribir una respuesta sería el equivalente a hacer tu tarea. Te explico la primera, y menos eficiente, pero te sirve para empezar y ya sobre eso puedes mejorar. Utiliza el método de fuerza bruta. Determina cual es el máximo de unidades que puedes comprar de cada uno de los artículos suponiendo que solo compraras de ese. Con este dato, puedes hacer dos ciclos anidados, desde 0 hasta este máximo de unidades. En el segundo ciclo mira a cuanto equivale comprar x unidades del artículo y y unidades del artículo dos.

Comment: Si ese valor está entre 39 y 42 mil, entonces, has encontrado una combinación, la imprimes y listo.

Comment: Y bueno, igual te hice más de la mitad de la tarea, el resto es que lo escribas en código.